# Ansible powershell scripts not working - script is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: powershell, ansible

I'm trying to stop windows services using ansible but I get the error 'script is not recognized \r\nas the name of a cmdlet."

Here is the task in the Ansible yaml file:

```
  - name: Check if ERL is already installed
    win_service:
      name: RabbitMQ
      state: stopped
```

This is the error when executing playbook:

```
TASK [Check if ERL is already installed] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "/home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1629089159.6-1896-227877656238414/AnsiballZ_win_service.ps1 : The term \r\n'/home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1629089159.6-1896-227877656238414/AnsiballZ_win_service.ps1' is not recognized \r\nas the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was \r\nincluded, verify that the path is correct and try again.\r\nAt line:1 char:1\r\n+ /home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1629089159.6-1896-22787765623841 ...\r\n+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (/home/user1/.an...win_service.ps1:String) [], CommandNotFoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException\r\n \r\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

Comment: so ... is there a file at `'/home/user1/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1629089159.6-1896-227877656238414/AnsiballZ_win_service.ps1'`? if so, does the account in question have permission to see/access/use it?